# How do I set up the Programmer Dvorak key layout on Mac OSX El Capitan?

Tags: keyboard, development, customization

I looked up the instructions for Dvorak on https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21495, but they do not seem to apply to my case, as they only list a way to *select* the Dvorak layout, and not a way to *install* and *select* the Programmer Dvorak layout.

I also followed the variations of the instructions related to Mac OSX Mavericks at the following link, to no avail:

http://www.kaufmann.no/roland/dvorak/macosx.html

After installing the layout driver package and following the instructions for "Adding Programmer Dvorak to the list of available layouts", even after a restart of the OS, and clearing of the layout cache by `sudo rm -f /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.IntlDataCache.le*` no Programmer Dvorak layout appeared.

I installed Mr. Kaufmann's package successfully, but it did not seem to change any of the listed keyboards.

Neither a search for "Dvorak" nor a search for "Programmer" gave me any good results for the Programmer Dvorak keyboard layout.

I can put screenshots, here, too, but I do not want to make this question too specific to my particular setup, as this is a general interest question and answer site.

I welcome specific answers as well as the usual steps for troubleshooting Programmer Dvorak Keyboard Layout installation on El Capitan.

Regardless, how do I set up Programmer Dvorak Keyboard Layout on El Capitan?

Comment: It is just impossible to help with so little info.  What exactly did not work when you tried to install the kaufmann.no package?  Did it never appear in system prefs/keyboard/input sources or in the "flag" menu at the top right of the screen?  Did it appear there but not type correctly, and if so, what exactly did not work right and what apps did you test it with.  Etc.

Comment: // , I'm not looking for troubleshooting for my specific setup. At this point, I am just looking for installation instructions for Programmer Dvorak Keyboard Layout on El Capitan. I would welcome more specific answers, though. Perhaps I can add some screenshots.

Comment: // , Perhaps you did not get a chance to read the article, @brmike, but it does not have any information about how to install the Programmer Dvorak Keyboard Layout on OS X El Capitan.

Comment: // , @bmike what are you _really_ asking of me, here? I'm trying to make this a general interest question, not free tech support. Sometimes that makes me err on the side of "vague" in the name of "general", but the goal is something that applies to _everyone_, not just my specific use case. Asking for a specific use case stunts the whole point of the stackexchange.com format, I think, since these are supposed to get general interest answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// , The following worked, in my case, for setting up the Programmer Dvorak key layout on Mac OSX "El Capitan":

**Adding Programmer Dvorak to the list of available layouts**

1. These steps must be performed from a user account with administrator access. By default, the main user of the computer has this capability.
2. Open Safari and download the layout driver package. Safari will put this file into the ~/Downloads folder, unpack it and then start the installer.
3. If you are on Mavericks (or later), you must hold down the Control key while you click the package icon, and then confirm to Gatekeeper that you want to open the package.
4. Choose Continue to skip the introduction screen of the package installer.
5. Make sure that your main harddisk is selected as the target of the installation, and then click the Continue button.
6. Click on the Install button to start installation.
7. Enter your password to make a system modification, and then click on the OK button.
8. Click on the Close button to acknowledge a successful installation.
9. Alternatively you can do an automated, non-interactive installation of the layout using this command:

   ```
   sudo installer -pkg "~/Downloads/Programmer Dvorak v1.2.pkg" -target /
   ```

**10. In El Capitan, you must now clear the layout cache before new layouts are recognized**:

```
sudo rm -f /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.IntlDataCache.le*
```

11. THEN restart your computer, check your list of available keyboard layouts, and clear the cache *again*. After another restart, your new keyboard layout should be available.

**Setting up your account to use the Programmer Dvorak layout** in *El Capitan*

1. Click on the Apple menu in the upper, left corner of the screen.
2. Choose System Preferences... from the menu that appears.
3. Click on the Keyboard icon in the second row in the window that
   opens.
4. Select the Input Sources header.
5. Click the + button in the lower, left corner.
6. Select the English language at the top of the list on the left side.
7. Select the Programmer Dvorak layout at the top of the list on the
   right side.
8. Click the Add button in the lower, right corner.
9. Tick the Show Input menu in menubar checkbox at the bottom of the
   window.
10. Close the Keyboard window.
11. Click on the Input Menu icon (the little keyboard or flag) in the
    upper-right corner of the screen.
12. Select Programmer Dvorak from the list that is displayed.

Comment: // , Your results may vary, but I tested this on the latest (at least, as of 20151008) 15" Retina Macbook Pro with OSX El Capitan installed, using a keyboard layout driver package and set of installation instructions, which I had to modify, from the following location: http://www.kaufmann.no/roland/dvorak/macosx.html.

Comment: Step 10 was *so* helpful. Had a bunch of apps switching the layout back to US for no apparent reason... Made DVORAK barely usable

Answer (score 1):

After clicking the + button, try scrolling to 'Others' and then look for the keyboard under there. I just installed a keyboard for the International Phonetic Alphabet and had the same problem. Good luck!

Comment: // , I'm curious, with which version of Mac OSX did this succeed?